# Understanding why my loop is not restarting

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I know in order to loop back to the start I need to enclose it in a "While" loop. However I already have a while loop to restart if the user inputs more characters than necessary. Should I change that condition? or is it possible to fix this without adding a function?

-edit- My fault for not being clear: Here's my actual code

```
abb_dict = {
    'lol': 'laughing out loud',
    'bfn': 'bye for now',
    'cuz': 'because',
    'omw': 'on my way',
    'tbh':'to be honest',
    'afk':'away from keyboard',
    'brb':'be right back',
    'afaik':'as far as i know',
    'np':'no problem',
    'rofl':'rolling on floor laughing',
    'asap': 'as soon as possible',    
}

for k, v in abb_dict.items(): # list all the abbreviations available to be translated
    print k, v
tweet_str = raw_input('Enter the sentence with an abbreviation in it :\n').lower()

while len(tweet_str) > 160: ## if tweet_str passes 160 characters it will display a message
    print "Too long, keep it less than 160 characters"
    tweet_str= raw_input('Enter the sentence with an abbreviation in it :\n').lower()# prompts user to re-enter new string

for k in abb_dict: # looks for any key variable in dictionary
        if k in tweet_str: # if the key is seen in the user input
            print k, abb_dict[k] # prints key variable along with dictionaries value which is the definition of the abbreviation

for key, value in abb_dict.iteritems():
    tweet_str = tweet_str.replace(key, value) #replaces abbreviations with their definition
print tweet_str
```

Comment: Is that your actual code or psuedo code?

Comment: Immediate response is `> 100` means 'greater than' 100, not 'less than'

Comment: Also, indentation. If the `for` loop and everything following is supposed to be in the `while` loop, it's not and that is a problem.

Comment: The rest of the code is not valid Python currently. I can't really work out what this code is supposed to do, but I'm guessing that the `for` loops are supposed to be under `while?`. Make sure your code is presented in the question as you see it so we can help. `for loop`... what is that?

Comment: @juan Then you *have* to give some context of what this is supposed to do. The `for` loops are outside of the `while` clause so what is supposed to be evaluated?

Comment: @roganjosh here is my code for you to get a better understanding http://pastebin.com/Cdnet4Jr

Comment: Your use of `while` loops is off, even after you correct the `<` / `>` mistake. I would have posted the real code rather than (invalid syntax) pseudocode; it's always best to provide an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but in this case you also need some description on expected behaviour

Comment: @roganjosh yeah i noticed when i tried changing the signs it ruined the rest of the program. Sorry for being to vague i'll try to be more clear in the future.

Comment: @roganjosh essentially this program is suppose look at the user's input and locate keys from the dictionary  and  then define those abbreviations . The program will then output the user's input with the replaced value's. This will only run when the user input is less than 160

Comment: Ok, to clarify. Program runs forever, always asking for user input. Any input over 160 chars is invalid (but keep asking). If input contains a recognised abbreviation... print input with the full version of abbreviation or just the meaning of the abbreviation?

Comment: Yes it will run until the user states not to. I plan to add a quit "Yes" or "No" conditonal statement later on to stop the loop but at the moment I am focused on this issue.

Example of my current output: 
 user input: I want to go afk...
  afk away from keyboard...
  I want to go away from keyboard...



I already accomplished that part however my loops are all messed up.

Comment: @roganjosh forgot to mention you.

Comment: @juan no worries, I was watching anyway. I think I have it covered in my answer for you to build upon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, this should get you started:

```
abb_dict = {
    'lol': 'laughing out loud',
    'bfn': 'bye for now',
    'cuz': 'because',
    'omw': 'on my way',
    'tbh':'to be honest',
    'afk':'away from keyboard',
    'brb':'be right back',
    'afaik':'as far as i know',
    'np':'no problem',
    'rofl':'rolling on floor laughing',
    'asap': 'as soon as possible',    
}

user_wants_to_play = True
while user_wants_to_play:
    check = raw_input('Do you want to play? y/n:')
    if check == 'y':
        tweet_str = raw_input('Enter a statement with an abbreviation: ')
        words = tweet_str.split(' ')
        rtn_sentence = []
        for word in words:
            try:
                replacement = abb_dict[word]
                word = replacement
                rtn_sentence.append(word)
            except:
                rtn_sentence.append(word)
        print ' '.join(rtn_sentence)
    else:
        user_wants_to_play= False
```

Comment: Thank you for a reference. I haven't worked with "try" or "except" statements yet since I am still new to python So I won't use them yet. I'll modify my current program and try to base it off your logic.

Comment: @juan if you're using dictionaries then your options are a `try` / `except` or `get` which will return `None` if it fails. Basically here, what it's doing in `try` is "do I know the full sentence for this abbreviation?" If it works, it gives you the sentence. The `except` is "No I don't, keep the word as it is". You can't avoid this kind of structure for long...

Comment: @juan also, this code should work as a self-contained program. If you copy/paste it to a script, it should do what you want it to. I made it verbose on purpose; stick some `print` statements in to see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will only run if the length of the string is greater than 100.

The code:

```
len(str) > 100
```

should be:

```
len(str) < 100
```

if you want the loop to execute if the length of the string is less than 100, as per your comment.

Comment: Alright so I am dumb, now I have to fix my code in order for it to work properly with everything.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have a linear program.

It collects a user input.

If the user input is too big, it keeps asking for input until it gets a small input.

It then does some processing on the input

It ends

---

If you want the whole system to repeat, you would need an outer loop and good exit criteria (when does the loop end). Something like the following psuedo-code.

```
str = raw_input
while toLower(str) != "exit"
  while len(str) > 100
  ...
  #your other code
  ...
  str = raw_input
wend
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem I mentioned in my comment with the mix-up of `>` and `<` and then takes giant leaps into predicting OP's intended output

Comment: His comments are self-contradictory.

"while len > 100", its comment "#loops for less than 100", and the print comment "print statement #print message over 100"

I went with the two statements that agreed rather than the one that disagreed. YMMV

Comment: Don't go to the effort of answering then until it's clear :P I've been burned on this with far bigger answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878226/compare-2-lists-and-create-new-list-with-different-results-in-python/34880659#34880659

Comment: It's been brought to my attention that my "while" statement conflicts with normal logic. Currently trying to fix my mistake